# Problem add submenu page

Tags: sub-menu

I have no access to my menu.

I am using the template Prolingua which I customized as well as wordpress.
Here is the error message :

> add_submenu_page is called the wrong way. The seventh parameter passed to add_submenu_page() should be an integer representing a menu position. Please read Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This post was added in version 5.3.0.) in /home/onanatraol/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4986

So what do I have to do to settle this very annoying problem?
Step by step please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried updating the theme? Of seems like the theme you are using isn't up to date with wordpress 5.3.0. You could disable wp debug to prevent that notice from popping up

Comment: Can you find the call to add_submenu_page that is passing the wrong seventh argument? I'd guess there is more call stack beneath that, and you want the one two lines down.